# spool file in oracle xe

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

hey ,
i am a newbie in oracle. i am using oracle xe . I just want to know  that is there a way to save queries and results in a file like in oracle u do by the query 
spool on
?
there must be a way but i cant find it.
thanx for your help

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quit simple but if someone is having the same problem you have to go to start->all programs->oracle database 10g express edition -> run sql command line. there after connecting (by using the connect command and giving user name and password onward) just write down spool c:/test.txt and here you go. and the spool file will be created in C:\Users\"your user name"\AppData\Local\VirtualStore...... i know i sound very obvious for 99% of you people but i am just trying to help out 1% remaining people like me . hope it will help :)